# C# - Inserting DataSet that contains relational DataTables into Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, insert, dataset

Hi I have a DataSet in C# which contains 3 DataTables. Two of the tables: SummaryLocal_Bands and SummaryLocal_Averages contain an fk relationship to the pk in the 3rd table: SummaryLocal. The tables in Sql Server have the same structure, columns, relationships, etc as the tables in this DataSet. Lets say I add rows to the DataTables in the DataSet so that they contain data. I then want to Insert their rows into the sql server tables (which contain the same structure as the datatables in the dataset as noted above). How hard is this to accomplish and how do I accomplish it? Or is it smarter to accomplish this another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is seems like you want to persist the changes on your DataTables to it's underlying tables in the database..can't you just make a connection to database and make an insert statement?...

Try creating a method that have the following commands below: (Note: it's just a skeleton of the commands that you need to do, fill them up according to your settings)

```
string connectionString = "your_connection_string";  
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);  

try  
{  
    con.Open();  
    string query = "insert statement";  

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))  
    {  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@some_parameter", "value_of_some_parameter");  
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    }   
}  
catch (Exception)  
{  
throw;  
}
```

Or, if your datatables are somehow not connected to a database, you can still use the above method by looping through the contents of your datatable.